Question about $f$ of bounded variation
Def.
The variation of $f$ on $[a, b]$ corresponding to a partition $P = \{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\},$
$V^P(f):=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})|.$
Obviously, if $Q$ is a refinement of $P$, then $V^P(f) \leq V^Q(f)$. If the set $\{V^P(f) : P \text{ is a partition of } [a, b]\}$ is bounded, then $f$ is called a function of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ and $V^{[a, b]}(f) := \sup_P V^P(f)$ is the total variation of $f$ on $[a, b]$.
Suppose that $f$ is of bounded variation on $(-\infty, \infty)$ and
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)| \,dx < \infty,$
do we have $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = 0 ?$

Please don't worry about the nosy people who want to make you include your entire life story before they deign to answer this super typical analysis question (motivation? source? why the question is relevant to you?? - why the heck do they want you to share all this private information?). Fortunately there are people who can just answer.

Yes.
Clearly $\liminf_{x \to \infty} |f(x)| = 0$, as otherwise the integral would diverge. Assume for contradiction that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} |f(x)| > 0$. Then we can find $\varepsilon > 0$ and an infinite sequence $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < x_3 < \ldots$ such that $|f(x_n)| \leqslant \varepsilon$ and $|f(y_n)| \geqslant 2 \varepsilon$. But this implies that the variation of $f$ is infinite, which is a contradiction.
The reasoning as $x \to -\infty$ is analogous.
